# configure packages without`provide` with `use-package`

Tags: use-package, isearch

How to configure packages, which have no `(provide <PACKAGENAME>)` call in their source code?

Immediate problem: configure `isearch` with use-package.
(Editing `isearch.el` is not an option because it may break updates and may trigger heavy bug hunting)

*Edit:* answering Drews comment: `use-package` can be used to cluster elisp code, which should belong to a package/library. The user is then able to write functions or set up keybindings, which are part of a users emacs configuration. Whith this technique it is possible to lazy load self written functions, or even redefine functions from a package *after* the package/library has been loaded. (Of course there are also other ways to do that but use-package is a nice Domain Specific Language for that kind of configuration).
By "configure" I mean writing a valid `use-package` sexp which serves the purpose of changing emacs default behavior.
Yes, with "Editing" I meant changing the source code file isearch.el. Emacs is hackable after all.

Comment: Strange, if I `M-x find-library RET isearch RET` and jump to the end of the file, I immediately find `(provide 'isearch)` there.

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by "configure" `isearch.el` (which is not a package, BTW)? There's no reason to `require` `isearch.el`, as it is loaded automatically. And why do you speak of *"editing"* `isearch.el` - are you trying to change some of its code? Unclear question, so far.

Comment: @wasamasa nice to know it has been fixed in recent versions of emacs. I'm using emacs 25.1 (part of distribution, and I dislike to upgrade, yet) there is no `(provide 'isearch)` in `isearch.el`

Comment: FYI, the missing provide was added in 2016: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/fd912a80cc9b88f2c0b155809b68e5f4a55bdb66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Immediate problem: configure `isearch` with use-package.

You can pass the filename as a string instead of a symbol (this is similar to `eval-after-load`, which is basically what the `use-package` macro expands to).

```el
(use-package "isearch"
  ...)
```

Another possibilty for builtin preloaded packages like isearch is to "use" the "emacs" package (since Emacs always provides the `emacs` feature):

```el
(use-package emacs ; isearch
  ...)
```

Or simply put the `provide` into your init file:

```el
(provide 'isearch)
(use-package isearch
  ...)
```

See also [Bug#25026 - Add missing (provide 'isearch)](https://debbugs.gnu.org/25026) (this is done as of Emacs 26.1).